# Can we use neither without a verb?

Tags: neither-nor

As I was reading the writing of a student, I saw this sentence:
*The teachers seem not to be perfectly trained for this situation, neither the students.*
I know 'neither do the students' is correct, but I was wondering if 'neither the students' is also grammatically correct. I could not find a definite answer to this question in several grammar books. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: The version as stated is not strictly wrong, because parallelism supplies the missing verb. (*Nor the students* would also work.) However, it's awkward because a verb would more commonly be used in this type of construction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OED has an entry for this: It is valid in Caribbean English but not current in British or American English

**Neither**

> **2. Negating a second or further alternative (usually following a previous negation): and not —— either, nor yet, nor moreover, and not, also not.**
>
> **a. Introducing a prepositional phrase, noun phrase, postmodifying phrase, etc. Now *chiefly Caribbean*.**
>
> 1560   J. Daus tr. J. Sleidane Commentaries f. xxvv   He said it was a matter newly invented, neither used in former time.   1937   P. M.
>
> 1937   P. M. Avery Interview 19 Mar. in C. L. Perdue et al. Weevils in Wheat (1976) 16   *I couldn' walk, neither set down.*
>
> 1996   R. Allsopp Dict. Caribbean Eng. Usage 403/1   *She don't talk to me, neither the children.*